# Replace sidekiq job with new instance in new queue if duplicate exist in other queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

My concern is that I have various queues of different priorities. (Eg: Q1,Q2,Q3).
If I have a job in a lower priority queue (say Q2), after some time i want to move it to higher priority queue (say Q1).

I am using sidekiq "cross-queue" uniqueness to check if duplicate job doesn't exist in some other queue. If it exist I want to change priority.

Event is Cron triggered after every 1 minute.

Need help on how to implement the same

Comment: what have you tried so far? what did not work?

Comment: I have been thinking about solutions and got two approaches:-                    1. Delete job from other queue and add in new queue                                2. Trying to find any inbuilt feature of sidekiq which can help. As we already have a cross queue check, it doesn't allow us to add new job, what I am looking for is replacing old job.

Comment: Any way i can get job id of existing queue job if duplicate is found. That way i will have exact job to delete and also would be able to add new job properly in other queue.